# Internationalisation with Spring

Tags: spring, internationalization, resourcebundle

I have an existing Spring/GWT Application which i need to add internationalisation to.  My understanding is that i can use Spring's "ResourceBundleMessageSource" to automatically select the appropriate messages_* file depending on the users location. I tried following [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-resource-bundle-with-resourcebundlemessagesource-example/) but i can't seem to get the Application to display my strings in French. As it stands, I've added 2 files messages_en_US.properties and messages_fr_FR.properties into my src/main/resources/i18n folder and added the following to the applicationContext.XML:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename">
        <value>classpath:i18n/messages</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
    <property name="interceptors">
       <list>
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Just wondering 1) if i need additional configuration/glue code and 2) if i can test this easily without having to set the Language/Locale to French on my Redhat Server?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your browser sends just "fr" language tag in Accept-Header. Spring is notorious for problems with fall-back, so you may need to copy the messages_fr_FR.properties as messages_fr.properties.

I am sure there must be some ways to configure fall-back, so you want have to use messages_en.properties (try your application with other English locales...), just messages.properties should do, but I am just too lazy/tired to look for solution at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to specify below bean in spring.xml.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
     <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    </mvc:interceptors>
```

This works perfectly fine when you pass **lang=es** in query string. If still any issue remain.you can check the working example [Here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7yo2HclmjI4QVJMR2p1M3NsZlk/edit?pli=1) .